# Mapping the oracle database directory object to a network path

Tags: oracle-11g

I'm an accidental DBA. We have oracle database running on windows server.

I created an oracle directory object named 'Result' and mapped it one of the local drives (C:\appResult) on the database server. The front end application creates a report and writes the file to 'Result' and a file thus gets written to C:\appResult. Now, we want to change the file path 'C:\appResult' to some other server in the network (another server in the network). What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about moving the path of the directory object, just use the Create or replace option :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY Result AS 'c:\newpath';
```

Comment: I want to provide a path that point to a different server in the network. Can I do this?

Comment: As long as the path is accessible from your local server, it should work.

"Oracle Database does not verify that the directory you specify actually exists. Therefore, take care that you specify a valid directory in your operating system. In addition, if your operating system uses case-sensitive path names, then be sure you specify the directory in the correct format. You need not include a trailing slash at the end of the path name."